# Keyboard key repeat rate and delay

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-events

Is there anyway to determine the key repeat rate and key repeat delay from within Java in a platform independant manner?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for Windows you could lookup the repeat rate in the registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard \ KeyboardSpeed

Various ways to access reg values in Java, here's one of them :

http://transoceanic.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/java-read-key-from-windows-registry.html